# Titanium Android Unable to find Android SDK API when building

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I am attempting to build my Titanium App for Android but it continuously complains about

```
[ERROR] Unable to find Android SDK API 23
[ERROR] Android SDK API 23 is required to build Android apps
```

Making sure that I have the Android API Level 23 (Marshmallow) installed:

[image: Installed API Levels]

Titanium still continues to output the above error. This happens when attempting to build an .apk and when attempting to run a debug build on my android device. Attempting to run a debug build on an emulator results in it complaining that no emulators were found even though emulators exist and are currently running.

Here is a full output from the build command:
[image: Build Output]

Here is the output from a Titanium Environment Check:
[image: Environment Check]
I have installed compatible versions of tools and platform-tools but the environment check seems to only relay information about the latest installed version.

What am I missing?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you resolve this problem?

Comment: I think this issue is related to the new `Android SDK Platforms-tools version 25.0.5` is the one you have installed?, Take a look of it in the SDK manager

Answer (score 1):

Google has deprecated its `android` command on the platform tools update `25.3.0`, that change is causing troubles with the Titanium SDK lower that `6.x.x` what you need to do is upgrade your Appc Titanium SDK project to at least version 6.0.4 or later. You can update it accessing to your tiapp.xml and change the line by the following one:

```
<sdk-version>6.0.4.GA</sdk-version>
```

I hope this information help you to fix this problem.

You can find here https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-24555 additional information regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a few days ago. The solution was to download an SDK tools version 24 and replace it in "/Users/nicolascantod/Library/android-sdk-macosx/tools"

link:
https://android-sdk.en.uptodown.com/mac/download

Comment: link is a spammy ad site

Comment: this link will save you life!

Answer (score 0):

1. Grab Android Studio https://developer.android.com/studio/
2. This installs the basics
3. You need to open a project, go to help and search for SDK Manager
4. Select the android platforms you want to support
5. Installation takes quite a while...